# Select all where one value (with a criteria) is higher then a value in a other table (with different criteria)

Tags: sql, oracle

What i want is the ID number of either Table 1 or 3 Where the value of a specific color is higher then that of a specific color in the other table.

Like: 
Select the ID's from Table 1 where the value of the Color 'Blue' in table1 is higher then the value of the color 'Purple'in table3 where the ID's match.

Table1

```
ID  |   Color   |   KeyA    |   KeyB
1   |   Blue    |   AB      |   12
2   |   Red     |   CD      |   34
3   |   Green   |   EF      |   56
1   |   Pink    |   EF      |   7
```

Table2

```
KeyA    |   KeyB    |   Value       
AB      |   12      |   10      
AB      |   34      |   20      
EF      |   56      |   40
```

Table3

```
ID  |   Color   |   KeyC    |   KeyD
1   |   Purple  |   QW      |   15
2   |   Yellow  |   ER      |   45
3   |   Orange  |   TY      |   78
```

Table4

```
KeyC    |   KeyD    |   Value       
QW      |   15      |   8       
TY      |   45      |   26      
TY      |   78      |   67
```

Table 1 and 3 are connected through the ID (NOT unique) 
Table 1 and 2 are connected on their KeyA and KeyB
Table 3 and 4 are connected on their KeyC and KeyD

It's probably something simple but I've been staring at this for to long to see it.

---

Eddit: The original Question has been answered by scaisEdge, but i have a follow up question.

Is it also possible to Select the ID from Table1, where the corresponding Value of the row where the Color is  'Blue' is higher then the corresponding Value of the row where the Color is 'Pink'?

Comment: Select the ID's from Table 1 where the **value** of the Color 'Blue' in table1 is higher then the value of the color 'Purple'in table3 where the ID's match . Which value are you talking about

Comment: @saravanakumarv the actual values(numbers)  in the Value column of the tables (Table 2 and Table 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use INNER JOIN for all the table  eg:

```
select t1.ID 
from table1 t1 
inner join  Table2 t2 ON t1.KeyA = t2.KeyA AND t1.KeyB = t2.KeyB 
inner join Table3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID 
inner join Table2 t4 ON t3.KeyC = t4.KeyC AND t3.KeyD = t4.KeyD 
WHERE  t2.value > t4.value
```

and id for blu and pink

```
select t1.ID 
from table1 t1 
inner join  Table2 t2 ON t1.KeyA = t2.KeyA AND t1.KeyB = t2.KeyB 
inner join Table3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID 
inner join Table2 t4 ON t3.KeyC = t4.KeyC AND t3.KeyD = t4.KeyD 
INNER JOIN table1 t5 on t1.id = t5.id and t1.color='Blue' and t5.color='Pink'
WHERE  t2.value > t4.value
```

Comment: This is the solution, Thank you.

Comment: I got a little follow up question if you don't mind. 
Is it possible to find the ID where the Color is 'Blue' and it's corresponding Value is larger then corresponding value of the same ID where the color is 'Pink' ? (All inside Table1)

Comment: answer  updated ..  hope is what you are looking for .. otherwise post a new question well described with proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892595/comparing-2-vaues-in-the-same-table-based-on-criteria-from-a-different-table

Posted a new question, i hope that is more clear.