# Comparing 2 vaues in the same table based on criteria from a different table

Tags: sql, oracle

What I want is to retrieve all ID''s Where the corresponding value of a color is higher then the corresponding value from a different color.
For example, I want where Value of 'Blue' is larger then the Value of  'Purple' Where the ID's match.

I have the following tables:
Table1

```
ID  |   Color   |   KeyA    |   KeyB
1   |   Blue    |   AB      |   13
1   |   Green   |   AC      |   15
1   |   Purple  |   AG      |   56
2   |   Purple  |   DF      |   46
2   |   Pink    |   GH      |   67
3   |   Orange  |   GH      |   89
3   |   Green   |   YU      |   97
```

Table2

```
KeyA    |   KeyB    |   Value       
AB      |   13      |   55      
DF      |   46      |   34      
YU      |   97      |   56      
DF      |   46      |   23      
AG      |   56      |   34
```

IN this example the result will be 1

Only the used Values:

Table1

```
ID  |   Color   |   KeyA    |   KeyB
1   |   Blue    |   AB      |   13
1   |   Purple  |   AG      |   56
```

Table2

```
KeyA    |   KeyB    |   Value       
AB      |   13      |   55      
AG      |   56      |   34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.keya = t1.keya and t2.keyb = t1.keyb
where t1.color in ('Blue', 'Purple')
group by t1.id
having max(case when t1.color = 'Blue' then t2.value end)
     > max(case when t1.color = 'Purple' then t2.value end);
```

Demo with your sample data in CTEs:

```
-- CTE to supply sample data for demo
with table1 (id, color, keya, keyb) as (
            select 1, 'Blue', 'AB', 13 from dual
  union all select 1, 'Green', 'AC', 15 from dual
  union all select 1, 'Purple', 'AG', 56 from dual
  union all select 2, 'Purple', 'DF', 46 from dual
  union all select 2, 'Pink', 'GH', 67 from dual
  union all select 3, 'Orange', 'GH', 89 from dual
  union all select 3, 'Green', 'YU', 97 from dual
),
table2(keya, keyb, value ) as (
            select 'AB', 13, 55 from dual
  union all select 'DF', 46, 34 from dual
  union all select 'YU', 97, 56 from dual
  union all select 'DF', 46, 23 from dual
  union all select 'AG', 56, 34 from dual
)
-- actual query
select t1.id
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.keya = t1.keya and t2.keyb = t1.keyb
where t1.color in ('Blue', 'Purple')
group by t1.id
having max(case when t1.color = 'Blue' then t2.value end)
     > max(case when t1.color = 'Purple' then t2.value end);

        ID
----------
         1
```

If you don't want to repeat the color names (and you aren't actually already binding them somehow) you could supply them in a CTE or an inline view instead:

```
select t1.id
from (
  select 1 as rnk, 'Blue' as color from dual
  union all select 2, 'Purple' from dual
) s
join table1 t1 on t1.color = s.color
join table2 t2 on t2.keya = t1.keya and t2.keyb = t1.keyb
group by t1.id
having max(case when s.rnk = 1 then t2.value end)
     > max(case when s.rnk = 2 then t2.value end);
```

---

If you want to see the colors and their values too you can use a subquery and analytic functions:

```
select id, color, value
from (
  select t1.id,
    t1.color,
    t2.value,
    max(case when t1.color = 'Blue' then t2.value end)
      over (partition by t1.id) as color1_value,
    max(case when t1.color = 'Purple' then t2.value end)
      over (partition by t1.id) as color2_value
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.keya = t1.keya and t2.keyb = t1.keyb
  where t1.color in ('Blue', 'Purple')
)
where color1_value > color2_value;
```

or with an inline view to remove duplication again:

```
select id, color, value
from (
  select t1.id,
    t1.color,
    t2.value,
    max(case when s.rnk = 1 then t2.value end)
      over (partition by t1.id) as color1_value,
    max(case when s.rnk = 2 then t2.value end)
      over (partition by t1.id) as color2_value
  from (
    select 1 as rnk, 'Blue' as color from dual
    union all select 2, 'Purple' from dual
  ) s
  join table1 t1 on t1.color = s.color
  join table2 t2 on t2.keya = t1.keya and t2.keyb = t1.keyb
)
where color1_value > color2_value;
```

which both give:

```
        ID COLOR       VALUE
---------- ------ ----------
         1 Blue           55
         1 Purple         34
```

Comment: I;m not familiar with "CTEs", would this mean that i have to add the entire part from "with" on the first line till the "select Id" in to the query?
Because of this is so it's not feasible seeing the real database had 1000's of Id's and dozens of colors.

Comment: No, the CTE is just for the demo as I don't have your actual tables. You just the need the first query - `select id from ...`.

Comment: This works, but i got a little question on the side. 
I want more then just the ID to be returned (also the color and the value). 
when i add those to the SELECT statement i will also have to add them to the GROUP BY statement. This makes the results null. Anyway around this?

Comment: O, i am using the first solution you provided.

Comment: @A.Bakker - I've added a way to do that, though on reflection it should probably have been a new question (albeit one that's been asked many times before too).

Comment: No possibility to do it without changing the FROM? Seeing it's part of a dynamic query with several possible filters working together. So it would be better/easier if everything that uses a variable is done in either the SELECT or the WHERE (sorry for being difficult haha)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use two time the t2 table    ..  should be

```
select t1.ID 
from table1 t1 
inner join t12 on t1.color = 'Blue'  and t12.color ='Purple'
inner join  Table2 t2 ON t1.KeyA = t2.KeyA AND t1.KeyB = t2.KeyB 
inner join  Table2 t22 ON t1.KeyA = t22.KeyA AND t12.KeyB = t22.KeyB 
WHERE  t2.value > t22.value
```

Comment: it says's purple and blue. (The id's do match)

Comment: in your previous commen  was "I got a little follow up question if you don't mind. Is it possible to find the ID where the Color is 'Blue' and it's corresponding Value is larger then corresponding value of the same ID where the color is 'Pink' ? (All inside Table1) "    pink  ..  so  ..  tell me .. .. now there are tow purple on for id 1 and one for id 2  ..

Comment: for the new question i took purple instead. 
And each ID has every color, every color/id combination has 2 values (KeyA and KeyB) that together are the key used to connect to the second table. There is a value for each unique key combination... I know it's confusing...this entire database is a 20 year old mess.

Comment: Also you are mentioning Tables 3 and 4 form the old question. Including in the WHERE. this code tries to compare the values of table 2 with a table that doe snot exist in this scenario.

Comment: This does not include the whole part about Blue and purple. How does it know that T2.value is supposed to be the value where the linked color in table1 is 'Blue' and how does T22.value know it's supposed to be the one linked to 'Purple'?